# collaborative Q n A management

Tags: content-management-system, collaboration

How to create a collaborative question answer management system like this one? I want to make one for my school where students can ask questions and find answers. I tried forums, pligg e.t.c. but they didn't appeal much. I want something exactly like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open-source Stack Overflow clone written in C# that's been mentioned a few times recently here called stacked, and the question has been asked before.

Related links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172516/a-stack-overflow-like-application-for-your-intranet
- http://code.google.com/p/stacked/

Comment: Thanks womble. I got what I wanted from the above links.(it was "Cahoots" based on PHP and MySql)